# Replacing several lines in a html file with sed, from a single csv file

Tags: html, bash, csv, sed, sh

I want to replace several lines in a html file using sed command, getting the information from a csv file.

This is an abstract of the html (Test.html) I want to edit, (the "/**/" are the lines to edit):

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Alerta',
        color: "orange",
/*1*/   data: [4, 3, 4]
        }, {
        name: 'Pre-Emergencia',
        color: "red",
/*2*/   data: [0, 0, 0]
        }, {
        name: 'Emergencia',
        color: "purple",
/*3*/   data: [0, 0, 0]
            }]
```

This is the CSV (Test.csv) from which I want to take the new values:

```
/*1*/       data: [3, 5, 5]
/*2*/       data: [1, 3, 1]
/*3*/       data: [10, 6, 4]
```

And this is the script I'm using right now (it works only to replace one line, from one csv file with a single line in it)

```
export TEST1="$(sed 's/ //g' Test.csv)" 
export TEST2="$(sed 's/ //g' Test.csv)" 
export TEST3="$(sed 's/ //g' Test.csv)"
sed -i -e '/*1*/c\'"$TEST1"'' Test.html
sed -i -e '/*2*/c\'"$TEST2"'' Test.html
sed -i -e '/*2*/c\'"$TEST2"'' Test.html
```

where I'm wrong? how should be the script to make it work?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

With single ***awk*** command:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]][[:space:]]+' 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2; next }
       $1 in a{ $2="  "a[$1] }1' Test.csv Test.html
```

The output:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Alerta',
        color: "orange",
/*1*/   data: [3, 5, 5]
        }, {
        name: 'Pre-Emergencia',
        color: "red",
/*2*/   data: [1, 3, 1]
        }, {
        name: 'Emergencia',
        color: "purple",
/*3*/   data: [10, 6, 4]
            }]
```

Comment: maybe I'm doing it wrong but when I add that line in the script, the terminal just display the html code, but nothing changes.

Comment: This solution works for me with the data given.  I have no idea why it works, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

I turn Test.csv into a list of sed commands and pipe it to sed:

`sed -e 's/\*/\\*/g' -e 's|data.*$|s/data.*$/&/|' Test.csv | sed -f- Test.html`

What this does:

- `-e 's/\*/\\*/g'` turn every `*` in Test.csv into `\*`
- `-e 's|data.*$|s/data.*$/&/|'` Turn `data: [3, 5, 5]` into `s/data.*$/data: [3, 5, 5]/`
- `sed -f- Test.html` take the sed commands from the pipe and run on Test.html

The intermediate output of `sed -e 's/\*/\\*/g' -e 's|data.*$|s/data.*$/&/|' Test.csv` is :

```
/\*1\*/       s/data.*$/data: [3, 5, 5]/
/\*2\*/       s/data.*$/data: [1, 3, 1]/
/\*3\*/       s/data.*$/data: [10, 6, 4]/
```

So, using the above commands against Test.html gets this output:

```
    series: [{
        name: 'Alerta',
        color: "orange",
/*1*/   data: [3, 5, 5]
        }, {
        name: 'Pre-Emergencia',
        color: "red",
/*2*/   data: [1, 3, 1]
        }, {
        name: 'Emergencia',
        color: "purple",
/*3*/   data: [10, 6, 4]
            }]
```